# How to retrieve 'y' and 'n' comma separated values as 'yes' or 'no' from a single column

Tags: query, csv

I have a table in a database with these columns

```
id     name    facility_Type
1      Taluka    y,n,n,y,n
```

Now I want to retrieve the comma separated values like this

```
id      name     Ambulance   ward  male_doctors  female_doctors  operation_theator
 1    Taluka      yes         no      no             yes              no
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? I'd guess you need to split the last column into substrings in order to parse the data into different columns. Syntax for that is database dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some databases would support something like this (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite).

```
select T.id,
       T.name,
       case substr(T.facility_type, 1, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as Ambulance,
       case substr(T.facility_type, 3, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as ward,
       case substr(T.facility_type, 5, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as male_doctors,
       case substr(T.facility_type, 7, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as female_doctors,
       case substr(T.facility_type, 9, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as operation_theator
from T;
```

If you are on SQL Server you need to type out `substring`.

```
select T.id,
       T.name,
       case substring(T.facility_type, 1, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as Ambulance,
       case substring(T.facility_type, 3, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as ward,
       case substring(T.facility_type, 5, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as male_doctors,
       case substring(T.facility_type, 7, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as female_doctors,
       case substring(T.facility_type, 9, 1) when 'y' then 'yes' else 'no' end as operation_theator
from T;
```

Comment: Be aware that if you filter based on that result, of you do that in a view and then `select * from yourview where ambulance='yes'` for instance, you are likely to force an index scan or worse a table scan. Of course if you search by something far more selective that is indexed as well as by these properties then that is a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

If your facility_Type is a fixed length, and then a rather static (non-dynamic) method of doing it would just be to identify the letter at position 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9.

You do not mention what database you use, but for **SQL Server** (for example) it could be done something like this:

```
SELECT
id, name,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 1, 1) = 'y' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 1, 1) = 'n' THEN 'No'
    ELSE NULL 
END AS Ambulance,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 3, 1) = 'y' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 3, 1) = 'n' THEN 'No'
    ELSE NULL 
END AS ward,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 5, 1) = 'y' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 5, 1) = 'n' THEN 'No'
    ELSE NULL 
END AS male_doctors ,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 7, 1) = 'y' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 7, 1) = 'n' THEN 'No'
    ELSE NULL 
END AS female_doctors,
CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 9, 1) = 'y' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(facility_type, 9, 1) = 'n' THEN 'No'
    ELSE NULL 
END AS operation_theator
from CTE
```

However, as mentioned it is a rather cumbersome way of doing things.

So if something which needs to run "better" and be more dynamic (for example if expanding the list with more options) I would recommend, finding a method of splitting the y,n,n,y,n into columns.

Again - this vary depending on which database system you use, so it's difficult to advice you on that specifically without more information.